# 1 inch threadless headset with hollow cap for cable routing

Tags: headset, cable, cable-routing

Lets skip the questions about why I want to do this, but I would like to run my front brake cable through my headset. This is an older race frame with a 1 inch headset. Most headsets built for this are BMX and I can't seem to find a 1 inch one. 
So I want to know if anyone knows of any parts that would work for me?
Also is there a way to jerry rig the "AheadSet Hollow Cap and Bolt 1 1/8 Threadless Freestyle" to make it fit?

Comment: https://www.bikewagon.com/part/headsets/stem-caps/aheadset-hollow-cap-and-bolt-1-1-8-threadless-freestyle
could I put a 1 inch cap and 1 inch star nut on this, and it would fit? I assume the bolt is wider than normal bolts.

Comment: The bolt and star nut for those are both way oversize, plus the hole in the top cap. It would be a metalworking project, but I can imagine trimming down the star nut to  size for 1". It's only 1/16" of material all around you'd be taking off. Run it with a 1 1/8 stem with a shim to make the top cap fit right.

Comment: I have personally drilled a hole down through the center of a bolt (I was making an oil extractor nipple for an alfine11 hub) and given a decent drill press/pillar drill and drill bits, and cutting fluid, and some jig to hold the bolt vertically, it was relatively straightforward.  The question is whether you can drill a big-enough hole for the cable outer and leave enough metal for structural strength.

Comment: Oh hey you might get away using two pieces of outer, and drilling a hole only big enough for an inner cable to pass down through.  Essentially making the bolt into two frame stops.  That would be one advantage of a mechanical brake over a hydraulic one in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [**Potts Mod**](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82978/19705)
which allows you to route the front brake cable down through the fork's steerer and out to the front brake caliper.

This will allow the front fork/wheel/bars to do a complete rotation without binding on cables.

A Potts Mod does not work for a back brake - for that you require a [detangler](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82979/19705) or to fit coaster brakes, aka back-pedal brakes.

Comment: yes, in a way, I thought the potts mod was just for threaded headsets.

Comment: @JohnBurgess same name, slightly different details I guess.  Would be quite awesome to use with a hydraulic front disk brake too, but would still be the same name.